# JQuery UI Combobox - Allow any valid value apart from the populated ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, combobox

I am currently displaying the years *2000,2001,2002* in a JQuery UI Combobox.

**My requirement is to allow the user to input manually any valid year.**

The JQuery UI Combobox seems to reject any values out of the populated year range.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.combobox').combobox()
      .addClass('overflow');
    });

function checkValidYearOfConstructions() {
    $(".custom-combobox-input").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only delete, backspace,left arrow,right arrow, Tab and numbers
        if (!((event.keyCode == 46 || 
            event.keyCode == 8  || 
            event.keyCode == 37 || 
            event.keyCode == 39 || 
            event.keyCode == 9) || 
            $(this).val().length < 4 &&
            ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)))) {
            // Stop the event
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkValidYearOfConstructions();
});

<sf:select class="form-control combobox" path="constructionYear" items="${contructionYearList}" disabled='<%= flag  %>'/>
```

Can somebody help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Siby Mathew

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Anybody got any idea on this ?